# C# Winform: Call External REST API With POST Method

Tags: c#

Hi I am Calling External Rest API, I have Get Correct Results of GET and One POST API Result But this gives the error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request . But in POSTMAN it is working fine.

In Postman I am Calling http://192.168.x.x:8088/ari/channels/100001.100/play?media=sound:hello-world&api_key=admin:admin&app=myapp1 .

My Code is below and I passing Parameters and query string in API.
I think my problem is in `media = sound:hello-world` but I have no idea to solve.

```
string  url = String.Format("http://192.168.x.x:8088/ari/channels/play?api_key=admin:admin");

WebRequest requestPost = WebRequest.Create(url);
requestPost.Method = "POST";
requestPost.ContentType = "application/json";

string  postData = "{\"channelId\":\"100001.100\",\"media=sound\":\"hello-world\",\"app\":\"myapp1\"}";
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestPost.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(postData);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();

}
var httpResponse = requestPost.GetResponse();

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var res = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you don't need to pass json. You should create the complete url as you are using in postman and assign it to webrequest object.

Comment: Could you use the Postman code feature to generate the HTTP code and add it to your question so we can see what is different?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Thanks: It's Working. Thanks a lot